# How can I get args of Form program?

Tags: c#, winforms, arguments, command-line-arguments

How can I get args of Form program? In console application I can use `args[]` but what about Form Application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One simple way:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Alternatively you could change the Main-call to include parameters (in Program.cs):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

You will then need to pass it into your Form, and change your form's constructor accordingly (assuming that's where you need the `args`):

```
public Form1(string[] args)
{
```

Comment: The first one works beautifully! I also figured out that it would be better to detect if it has more than 1 argument, then get the one at index 1.

Comment: Great. :) I have often used Nini for both config reading and command line parsing: http://nini.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Looks quite interesting :)   It seems as if it's dead though, with the update being in 2010... :/

Comment: True, but it still works great (and I haven't found any good replacement so far). Someone also put a copy in NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a WinForm application in C# the editor creates a Program.cs file for you.  That is where main is located and that is where the arguments are available.

It's a bit of IDE "magic" for lack of a better term.  There is still a 'main' function, it just launches an instance of your main form does and anything else that is required for you. Open that file up and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the form constructor to accept an args parameter.

eg:

```
public void Form1(string[] args)
{

}
```

Comment: stefan's answer is also correct. Are you passing args to the application or form?

Comment: It is the Main()-entry that takes args, not the Form.